# Confusion about the F1_score calculation

Tags: machine-learning

I'm trying to figure out the proper way to calculate the F1_score manually.

Here is an example that I find form sklearn page:
actual label = [0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2]
prediction = [0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 1]

The F_1 score given by sklearn is 0.8 for label "0"

I'm trying to replicate this F1_score

So for label "0":
The 1st is TP
The 2nd is FN
The 3rd is FN
The 4th is TP
The 5th is FP
The 6th is FN

So we have in total 2 TP, 1 FP and 3 FN, which gives us precision = 2/3 and recall = 2/5, hence the F1 score = 2 * precision * recall / (precision + recall) = 0.5

Can someone please help to point out where I went wrong.  Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

FN means that the truth is 0, but it is predicted to be 1 or 2. So  in total 2 TP, 1 FP and 0 FN.

```
precision = 2/(2+1)=2/3 and recall = 2/(2+0)=1
F1 score = 2 * precision * recall / (precision + recall) = 0.8
```

Comment: @EricNguyen  Happy to help. Don't forget to accept the answer as accepted if it solved your problem.